# Sticky footer with center column set to 100% height

Tags: css

I got my sticky footer working, but I would like my test container to reach from the top of the browser to the footer. How can I do this? It's working except the height of the center column.

HTML:

```
<div id="wrap">
  <!--All of your content goes here-->
  <div id="test">test</div>
  <div class="push"></div>
</div>
<div class="pagefooter">footer</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body { width:100%; height:100%; }
#wrap { 
min-height:100%;
height:auto !important;
height:100%;    
margin: 0 auto -158px;  /* Bottom value must = footer height */
}

.pagefooter, .push { width:100%; height:158px; position:relative; bottom:0; }


#test{
    background-color: red;
    height:100%;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#wrap{width:100%;display:table;}
#test{display:table-row;}
```

And remove `.push` div.

[**Fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/GCQ8d/1/)

Comment: Kind of works. Only problem is the footer doesn't stop when reaching content.

Answer (score 0):

With html5, flex might be helpful.

```
#wrap { 
   ...
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

   #test{
    ...
    flex: 1;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qz34C/

Comment: Very nice. Works the way I want. I need to do research which browsers supports this.

Comment: Hmmm would like to support IE9 at least.

Comment: `display: flex;` is still not supported on most browsers, IE9 is way too old to support it. - @user874774

Comment: @NathanLee thanks. I saw that. Otherwise this worked as I wanted.